# How to find minimum rank of the Pricepoint

Tags: java-8, maps

Can anyone please guide me how to map the results of inner map with outer map. I have created a Pricepoint object with List holding Id,Pricepoint,Rank which i have mapped to inner map by getting minimum rank for each pricepoint, now I want to map the results with their specific Id's. Thanks

```
public class Pricepoint {

String id;
String pricepoint;
int rank;

public Pricepoint(String id,String pricepoint,int rank)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.pricepoint = pricepoint;
    this.rank= rank;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getPricepoint() {
    return pricepoint;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Comparator<Pricepoint> comp = (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare( p1.getRank(), p2.getRank());
    List<Pricepoint> p = new LinkedList<>();
    p.add(new Pricepoint("1","PP1",1));
    p.add(new Pricepoint("2", "PP1", 2));
    p.add(new Pricepoint("3","PP2",3));
    p.add(new Pricepoint("4", "PP2", 4));
   Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map1 =   p.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pricepoint::getPricepoint,Pricepoint::getRank,Math::min))// I'm struck here
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. How does your results look like?

Comment: I need output as pricepoint records only with  minimum rank as below {1=pp1=1,3=pp2=3}

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want something like this if I am not mistaken:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map1 = p.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Pricepoint::getPricepoint,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                    Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Pricepoint::getRank)),
                                    Optional::get)),
                    (Map<String, Pricepoint> x) -> {
                        return x.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        entry -> entry.getValue().getId(),
                                        Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getRank())));
                    }));

    System.out.println(map1);
```

but this is just insanely complicated... I honestly hope you really have a use case for this.

Comment: Thanks for the code but I need output as {1=pp1=1,3=pp2=3}